# SQL select rows if a column value is not in a group of a different column's values

Tags: mysql, sql, join, group-by, hive

For each **identifier**, how can I return the **quantity** when the  **received** country is not equal to any of the **delivered** countries? I need an efficient query for the steps below since my table is huge.

These are the steps I would think could do this, of course you don't need to follow them :)

1. Create a group of 'delivered' countries for each identifier.
2. See if 'received' is any of these countries for each identifier. If
   there is no match, return this result.

Starting Table:

```
identifier         delivered            received        quantity
-------------      ------------         -----------     ------------
1                  USA                  France          432
1                  France               USA             450
1                  Ireland              Russia          100
2                  Germany              Germany         1,034
3                  USA                  France          50
3                  USA                  USA             120
```

Result:

```
identifier         delivered            received        quantity
-------------      ------------         -----------     ------------
1                  Ireland              Russia          100
```

The starting table is about 30,000,000 rows, so self-joins will be impossible unfortunately. I am using something similar to MySQL.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think `LEFT JOIN` query should work for you:

```
SELECT a.*
FROM starting a
     LEFT JOIN starting b
        ON a.id = b.id
           AND a.delivered = b.received
WHERE b.received IS NULL;
```

## Example: [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/66195/1)

For optimizing above query, adding following composite index should give you better performance:

```
ALTER TABLE starting  ADD KEY ix1(id, delivered, received);
```

Comment: this, or a "... WHERE received NOT IN ( SELECT delivered WHERE identifier = 1 )" should also do.

Comment: Won't this produce a cartesian product? If my starting table were as above, how many rows would this produce while processing?

Comment: The question does say "self-joins will be impossible"

Comment: The original table is almost a billion rows, so if I start producing cross products, the query probably won't work.

Comment: No it doesn't produce cartesian product. This query can make use of indexes. Check with `EXPLAIN` or see `View Execution Plan` here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/66195/1

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `not exists` subquery:

```
SELECT  a.*
FROM    starting a
WHERE   NOT EXISTS
        (
        SELECT  *
        FROM    starting b
        WHERE   a.id = b.id
                AND a.delivered = b.received
        )
```

This is not a self-join, but the query optimizer is free to execute it as one (and usually does.)